# A mesh of ellipsoids in Octave

Tags: matlab, geometry, octave, mesh, ellipse

I am trying to build a triangular mesh that comprises of a number of ellipsoids. My attempt is to first create a surface that is union of two ellipsoids and keep on taking its union with new ellipsoids in a loop. The OCTAVE code is as follows:

```
close all; clear all; clc;
[x, y, z] = ellipsoid(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 30);
[x2, y2, z2] = ellipsoid(.5, 0, 0, 3, 1, .5, 30);

x = [x; x2]; y = [y; y2]; z = [z; z2];
surf(x, y, z);
axis equal;
```

The output is a surface that has both the ellipsoids. I want the interior of the the surface to be hollow, i.e., there should be no points inside the surface and it should be closed. I tried finding points of the second ellipsoid that are interior to the first one using the following:

```
idx = (x2.^2+y2.^2+z2.^2) < 1;
```

But this doesn't help as `idx` cannot index `x, y, z`.

Can anyone guide me how to create a union of two ellipsoids and from there form a triangular mesh? My surfaces will always be ellipsoids and therefore, a general meshing technique may be an overkill.